# Strange assignment to __dict__ in constructor

Tags: python, oop

I've been reading some code online and came across a strange line I couldn't understand, in a piece of code like this:

```
class SomeObject():
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        self.__dict__ = {}  # that's the line
```

I don't understand why assigning an empty dictionary for the object's attributes would ever make sense. Can you explain?

Thanks.

Comment: Where did you find this code? I suspect it is a pedagogical example demonstrating what `self.__dict__` means, by showing that if you replace it with an empty dictionary then the properties (such as `name` here) disappear.

Comment: Not at all. I read a chapter about python compilation and the class is meant to have callable methods, so obviously it's a mistake. I wonder why doing this would ever make sense.

Comment: Could you put some more of the context that you saw this code in into the question? The class's methods aren't stored in the object's `__dict__`, methods are looked up from the class, so that wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @kaya3, thank you for your help. I understand this now and I'm convinced it's an error on the author's part.